# Trying to add to get information from an api call to my backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, axios

I get a list of recipes from a third party API after I render the list. I want to add specific ones to a favorites list when I pressure the Fav button. However, whenever I try to render the list of recipes I get the error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'addtoFavorites' of undefined"

Any help would be appreciated.

When I remove the "onClick={this.addtoFavorites.bind(this)}" the component renders as expected. I don't know why addtoFavorites is undefined

```
class RecipeList extends Component {

addtoFavorites = (ev) => {
      const val = ev.target.dataset.value;
      this.props.recipeToFavorite(val);
      console.log(val)  

renderRecipe(recipeData) {
    let recipeName = recipeData.recipeName;
    let recipeId = recipeData.id;
    let recipeIngredients = recipeData.ingredients.join(", ");
    let recipeURL = "https://www.yummly.com/recipe/" + recipeData.id;
    let recipeImage = recipeData.smallImageUrls;
    var recipeDataObj = { name:recipeName, recipeID:recipeId, recipeImage:recipeImage, recipeURL: recipeURL }
  }

    return (
      <div>
      <div key={recipeData.id}>
              <div>
                <img
                  src= {recipeImage}
                  alt="FoodPic"
                />
                <h4> {recipeName} </h4>
                <div>
                  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
                </div>
                <ul>
                  {recipeIngredients}
                </ul>
                <h6>
                  <a href={recipeURL}>
                    Recipe
                  </a>
                </h6>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button
              onClick={this.addtoFavorites.bind(this)}
              data-value={recipeDataObj}
            >
              Fav
            </button>
          </div>
          );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 className="">Recipes</h2>
        <div className="">{this.props.recipes.map(this.renderRecipe)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ recipes }) {
//console.log("List Recipes", recipes)
  return {
    recipes
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RecipeList);

import _ from "lodash";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { compose } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../Actions";

class FoodList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchFoodList();
  }

  addIngredientToPot = ev => {
    const val = ev.target.dataset.value;
    this.props.addToPot(val);
  };

  onDeleteClick = ev => {
    const val = ev.target.dataset.value;
    this.props.deleteFood(val);
    this.props.fetchFoodList();
  };

  displayFoodList() {
    return _.map(this.props.foods, food => {
      return (
        <tr key={food._id}>
          <td
            onClick={this.addIngredientToPot.bind(this)}
            data-value={food.name}
          >
            {food.name}
          </td>
          <td>{food.type}</td>
          <td>{food.count}</td>
          <td>{food.created_at}</td>
          <td>
            <button
              data-value={food._id}
              onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this)}
            >
              Throw Out
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div />
          </div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Count</th>
                    <th>Date Added</th>
                    <th>Throw Out</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>{this.displayFoodList()}</tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    foods: state.foods,
    pot: state.pot
  };
}
export default compose(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    actions
  )
)(FoodList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the **addtoFavorites** method into a regular function instead of an arrow function like this.

```
class RecipeList extends Component {

constructor() {
  this.addtoFavorites = this.addtoFavorites.bind(this);
}

addtoFavorites (ev){
      const val = ev.target.dataset.value;
      this.props.recipeToFavorite(val);
      console.log(val)  
}

renderRecipe(recipeData) {
    let recipeName = recipeData.recipeName;
    let recipeId = recipeData.id;
    let recipeIngredients = recipeData.ingredients.join(", ");
    let recipeURL = "https://www.yummly.com/recipe/" + recipeData.id;
    let recipeImage = recipeData.smallImageUrls;
    var recipeDataObj = { name:recipeName, recipeID:recipeId, recipeImage:recipeImage, recipeURL: recipeURL }
  }

    return (
      <div>
      <div key={recipeData.id}>
              <div>
                <img
                  src= {recipeImage}
                  alt="FoodPic"
                />
                <h4> {recipeName} </h4>
                <div>
                  <h3>Ingredients</h3>
                </div>
                <ul>
                  {recipeIngredients}
                </ul>
                <h6>
                  <a href={recipeURL}>
                    Recipe
                  </a>
                </h6>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button
              onClick={this.addtoFavorites}
              data-value={recipeDataObj}
            >
              Fav
            </button>
          </div>
          );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 className="">Recipes</h2>
        <div className="">{this.props.recipes.map(this.renderRecipe)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ recipes }) {
//console.log("List Recipes", recipes)
  return {
    recipes
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RecipeList);
```

Comment: thanks but it still doesn't work the same error shows up: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addtoFavorites' of undefined

Comment: @JosueGuzman i have update my answer. btw are you using create react app?

Comment: Yea I am using Create React App boilerplate. I've tried your suggestions but it's still doesn't seem to be working. I am confused why this I can't call the function with the onClick in this case because in the same project I a separate file where I have to onClick event listeners and they work the way I expect them too. I pasted the separate file below this is the one I used a template for the current file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're read *Main concepts* from the docs, this is explained under [handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

`You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default`. Read more about autoboxing on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Boxing_with_prototype_and_static_methods)

Also `arrow functions` does not have *own* `this`. ([MDN](http://this.addtoFavorites.bind(this))) So when you do `this.addtoFavorites.bind(this)`, there is no `this` to bind to.

So the possible ways to handle events (as per docs):

**Define handlers as regular javascript functions and bind in constructor** so in your case

```
constructor(props) {
  // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
  this.addtoFavorites = this.addtoFavorites.bind(this);
}

function addtoFavorites (ev) {
```

**using the experimental public class fields syntax** you can use class fields to correctly bind callbacks (not sure if this is still experimental):

```
// This syntax ensures `this` is bound within handleClick.
// Warning: this is *experimental* syntax.
addtoFavorites = (ev) => {
  ...
```

**using arrow function in the callback**

```
addtoFavorites = (ev) => {

onClick={(e) => this.addtoFavorites(e)}
```

Note however if you use this solution (from docs): *The problem with this syntax is that a different callback is created each time the LoggingButton renders. In most cases, this is fine. However, if this callback is passed as a prop to lower components, those components might do an extra re-rendering.*

React's recommendation is to use the `binding` solution.

*We generally recommend binding in the constructor or using the class fields syntax, to avoid this sort of performance problem.*